# The best way to torture a character with modern technology

Tags: torture

Welcome to the Ministry of Amity! Here in the People's Utopia, we have one of the lowest crime rates in the world! <sup>Be warned: questioning our statistics is a crime.</sup> Due to the hard work and perseverance of our brethren in MiniFact, hardly anybody becomes a criminal in the first place. After all, everybody loves Big Sister!

However, it is with great sorrow that I must inform you that, for some reason, people occasionally commit the crime. When we can, we, ah, reform them; unfortunately, some people just refuse to end their contumacy. Since our concern is with love, not hate, <sup><insert excruciating screams in the background here></sup> **we have decided to ask you, our noble citizen doctors, engineers, and scientists, to find us a good way to increase the effectiveness of our reconciliation programs.**

Your criteria:

1. The <strike>thought-criminal</strike> <strike>heretic</strike> disillusioned person must be kept alive as long as possible.
2. They must be put in as much pain as possible. Mental pain is slightly preferable, as physical pain is so cliche.
3. Unfortunately, a perfect society does not always mean perfect society; the technology at our disposal hasn't advanced much since the 21th century <sup>I wish we had nanotech, but Miniplenty has forbidden it. Oh well.</sup>
4. Physical disfigurement is no issue. <sup>We've found that a "reminder" is very effective in preventing relapses.</sup>
5. We'd prefer to keep the subjects' minds more or less intact; you can't repent if you're insane. <sup>Just remember, 2+2=5.</sup>

Finally, the Ministry of Factuality has, after [much discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/we-cannot-host-gruesome-depictions-of-violence-the-torture-tag-has-it-and-nee), asked us to remind you that here in the People's Utopia **we like to keep descriptions strictly clinical.** Violators will be subjected to their own <strike>torture</strike> correction methods. You have been warned.

Comment: "*The Good Place*" spent the first two seasons exploring this, with the addition of magic. Torture is other people.

Comment: Just because we're being watched... [Go read this meta statement from our SE overlords](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/40609) and make absolutely sure you're cool with answers that are 100% clinical and therefore might not meet all of your expectations. (The reason you're getting down votes is that meta statement. Torture and execution questions are not very popular right now.)

Comment: @JBH Considering that the second answer down was written by me, you might say that I am familiar with that post. If absolutely clinical descriptions don't meet all of my expectations, then so be it; I absolutely agree that gore does not belong on this site (FYI, that's also why I included the "mental pain is preferable" part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Electro shock.

Human body can take a lot of pain via electricity without leaving a mark. It also is perfect correction tool. Someone once showed me a dog shock collor, for very small dogs and very low power, and said "just tap your finger on the prongs and press the button. It's not bad, see." I pressed the button and no it didnt hurt that much. I tried again, still didnt hurt. I tried again and my finger physically wouldnt press against the prongs, it hovered about 1mm away even though I was trying to reconnect it. My brain had just noped and wouldnt let that occur again even though I was mentally ok with it.

So my suggestion is to crank this up.

You have many choices here:

- Pure random. This will teach "learned helplessness" and they will learn nothing they say or do will stop the pain. (This is what dog shock collars often teach inadvertently.) They will be shy, withdrawn, and distant.
- Hook it up to a brain wave sensor, zap them if they think too much. This way they associate thinking with pain, which sounds like what your 2+2=5 stuff is all about.
- If you can hook your sensors up precisely you can detect different thought patterns. Make them read your manifesto from memory without activating the critical thinking brainwaves. Then do a q and a on it to them, they have to answer without critically thinking.
- instruct them to do monotonous tasks continuously, and zap them if they slightly hesitate. If combined with the "zap if you think" this can also make a very obedient subject.
- You may get other answers that inflict slightly greater physical pain, but in most of them the victim can detach into their own fantasy world to survive mentally. By hooking a brainwave sensor up to electro shock you can be certain they don't escape into their own minds.

Comment: That's an interesting anecdote about the dog collar. I find my own physical courage is at it's lowest ebb when it comes to knowingly discharging static electricity, something I've never thought about until now!

Comment: Although our goal is to "correct" thoughts, not abolish them, we at the Ministry of Amity can adapt your method easily enough. You're hired.

Comment: Also, I tried that a while back with a (somewhat bigger) shock collar, and I had the same reaction.